# ReSharper: any other way to suppress a warning other than with a comment?

Tags: resharper, resharper-8.0

I am getting ReSharper warning which I would like to suppress in this particular case (but not for the entire project). At the moment the only way to do it is to suppress it with a comment. However it looks ugly!

```
// ReSharper disable StaticFieldInGenericType
        private static int count;
// ReSharper restore StaticFieldInGenericType
```

I simply don't like to see these ReSharper comments in my code.

Is it somehow possible to keep these settings in a separate file, e.g. - `SupressedInspections.ReSharper`, etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can only disable it inline with the comments. The best you can do is use ReSharper 8's terser, one line version:

```
// ReSharper disable once StaticFieldInGenericType
```

Comment: Thank you @citizenmatt. Does ReSharper have a uservoice page where I can suggest this?

Comment: No, we use our own issue tracker - dog fooding! You can report bugs or make suggestions at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com